# Ruby base_auth with net/http - undefined method `user' for String

Tags: ruby

I've got pure Ruby app where I want to create request to external API. To do so I'm using standard Ruby Net::HTTP like below:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

  class Api
    BASE_URI = 'https://staging.test.com'
    WORKFLOW = 'tests'
    QUIZ_PATH = "/v3/accounts/workflows/#{WORKFLOW}/conversations"

    def initialize(payload:)
      @payload = payload
    end

    def post_quiz
      handle_response(Net::HTTP.post_form("#{BASE_URI}#{QUIZ_PATH}", options))
    end

    attr_reader :payload

    private

    def options
      {
        basic_auth: basic_auth,
        body: payload.to_json,
        headers: headers
      }
    end

    def basic_auth
      {
        username: Settings.ln_username,
        password: Settings.ln_password
      }
    end

    def headers
      {
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
      }
    end

    def handle_response(response)
      return response.body if response.success?
    end
  end
```

But instead of response I'm getting an error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for #String:0x00007f80eef9e6f8
> Did you mean?  super

> /Users/usr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:527:in `post_form'

I don't have any user there, what is it?

Comment: Please add more from that error trace.

Comment: @razvans I added `/Users/usr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:527:in post_form'` in addition there are paths to the file in which it is called

Answer (score 1):

`Net::HTTP.post_form` is used to send FormData pairs - its not what you want to send JSON and it doesn't even allow you to send headers (You're actually putting them in the request body!).

If you want to send a POST request with HTTP Basic auth and custom headers and JSON body you need to create the request object manually:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

class Api
  BASE_URI = 'https://staging.test.com'
  WORKFLOW = 'tests'
  QUIZ_PATH = "/v3/accounts/workflows/#{WORKFLOW}/conversations"
  attr_reader :payload

  def initialize(payload:)
    @payload = payload
  end

  def post_quiz
    url = URI.join(BASE_URI, QUIZ_PATH)
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url, headers)
    request.basic_auth = Settings.ln_username, Settings.ln_password
    request.body = @payload.to_json
    # open a connection to the server
    response = Net::HTTP.start(url.hostname, url.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
      http.request(request)
    end
    handle_response(response)
  end

  private


  def headers
    {
      'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0',
      'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    }
  end
 
  # How to respond from an API client is a whole topic in itself but a tuple or hash might 
  # be a better choice as it lets consumers decide what to do with the response and handle stuff like logging
  # errors
  def handle_response(response)
     # Net::HTTP doesn't have a success? method - you're confusing it with HTTParty
    case response
    when Net::HTTPSuccess, Net::HTTPCreated 
      response.body
    else  
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As you might have gathered by now Net::HTTP is ridicously clunky and is the worst part of the Ruby standard library as its so poorly designed and hasn't actually been substantially changed since earliest days of the language. If you don't want to torture yourself use a HTTP library such as HTTParty or Faraday.

Comment: Voting up. I wanted to write something like this eventually, after going back and forth with OP. Thanks.

Comment: Agree, it's super annoying but unfortunately HTTParty is not working inside the AWS Lambda (didn't checked with Faraday but it's much complex gem so I assume it's the same case)

Comment: Ok in that case if you're stuck with it the basic gist is that you create request objects which are subclasses of `HTTP::GenericRequest` and then you send them and it gives you back a subclass of `HTTP::Response` depending on the response code. The rest is just a myriad of convenience methods of varying usefulness - it was was written way before keyword arguments where a thing so the interfaces are horrible.

Comment: I think it should be `request.basic_auth(Settings.ln_username, Settings.ln_password)` instead of `request.basic_auth = Settings.ln_username, Settings.ln_password` becasue of error: `NoMethodError: undefined method basic_auth=' for #<Net::HTTP::Post POST>` but even after that change it shows me `NameError: undefined local variable or method uri' for #<LexisNexis::Api:0x00007fa3a8a18788>
Did you mean?  URI`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code that raises the error:

```
def HTTP.post_form(url, params)
  req = Post.new(url)
  req.form_data = params
  >> req.basic_auth url.user, url.password if url.user
  start(url.hostname, url.port,
        :use_ssl => url.scheme == 'https' ) {|http|
    http.request(req)
  }
end
```

From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html):

> post_form(url, params)
>
> Posts HTML form data to the specified URI object. The form data  must be provided as a Hash mapping from String to String.

That means `Net::HTTP.post_form(URI("#{BASE_URI}#{QUIZ_PATH}"), options)` fixes it. You are currently sending a string as url instead of a URI.

Comment: `Net::HTTP.post_form(URI("#{BASE_URI}#{QUIZ_PATH}"), options)` gives me an error: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Net::HTTPUnauthorized into String`.

Comment: This error is something else entirely. You probably have a login on your endpoint. The answer fixes the code to successfully send the request to the endpoint.  Update with the trace for this new error.

Comment: No, it's not. Your answer didn't fixed my problem - I've got basic_auth as you see and your code is incorrect. I've checked everything with HTTParty and it works well but I cannot use this gem inside AWS lambda so I need net//http version.

Comment: I'm saying it again. My answer fixes exactly what you mention in the question. It helps you move past an error to ... another one. Another error that's not written anywhere and we, the guys who answer, cannot possibly know all the time. It's not fair to vote down an answer that helps. @max always writes thorough answers and that's how your code should look like.